# Cannot resolve symbol exception after editing dbml

Tags: c#, database, exception, dbml

I am stumped:

I have a program that is interacting with several databases.  These database connections were made via Server Explorer with all necessary tables brought in.  Each table has a ID column that is the primary key in the SQL database.

I learned, after running my code, that I need these IDs to auto generate, because they need to be unique, but it doesn't matter what numbers they are, as long as they are unique.  In the .dbml file, I found if I click on the ID field in a table, it has a boolean property for "Auto Generated Value".  PERFECT!

But when I change it from false to true, it seems to cause my program to lose access to every other field in every other table of that database.  All of my code that was working fine, is now in red where it accesses those fields, with the error "cannot resolve symbol".  I have been working on this for a while and just cannot figure out why it is doing this.  Through Team Explorer, I have been able to revert back to before I made this change, so I have been able to reproduce and verify that simply changing the ID's "Auto Generate Value" property from false to true causes this.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: can you just show me your database structure!

Comment: Sure.  Do you want to see the dbml graphic with the tables, or the class where it's written out?